# Complex column.(Id + string)

Tags: sql, nhibernate

I have a table which has a string column. This column should consist of some text + id of current row. Id generated by database.

For example:  Row :   (Id) 12,  (MyColumn) 'abcde12'

What is the best way to do it? Can i do it with NHibernate, or it can be done only with SQL?

Comment: Does the "some text" that you mention come from another column in the same table? If not, do you know what "some text" will be, before the insert of a new record?

Comment: No it is came from client. It text generated by some complex rules on client.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this does answer your question directly but what about this approach instead:

```
public virtual string MyCalculatedField {
  get { return MyColumn + Id.ToString(); }
}
```

By doing this you don't have to incur a double update after the DB has generated your ID.

Comment: But what if someone who use this database want to read this field with another model or just with SQL Query?

Comment: Yes that is a limitation of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by "id generated by database", you might have to split the insertion of new records into two steps.

If your id is generate by something like MySQL's autoincrement, it would look like this:

```
Insert into your_table (some_text_col)
Values ('some_text')
```

This will get you

```
ID   some_text_col   combined
 1   'some_text'      Null
```

You can than update that column with

```
Update your_table
set combined = concat(some_text_col, id)
where id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Note: This should work for MySQL, though I did not test it. It could be easily adapted for other DBMS. You might want to consider using triggers (if your DB supports them) to automate the `Update`.

Comment: I think @@IDENTITY only works in SQL Server. MySQL uses LAST_INSERT_ID().

Answer (score 0):

Why store the `12` in two places?

Store `12` in the `ID` column and `abcde` in `MyColumn`.

When you want to retrieve, you can concat the two values or retrieve them as separate columns, whatever is needed by applications. Or you can use a `View`:

```
CREATE VIEW Extra AS
( SELECT ID
       , MyColumn
       , CONCAT(ID, MyColumn) AS ExtraColumn
  FROM TableX
) ;
```

Then you can use:

```
SELECT ExtraColumn FROM Extra
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM Extra
```